# How can I use markdown on my vuejs projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

How can I use **markdown** in **vue.js** instead of Paragraph on my Html file

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good examples online for this, for example:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/

Either install the npm package **marked** or include it using script tags as shown in the example:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/marked@0.3.6"></script>
```